# crypted password issue with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to change the password to be crypted before it is inserted in the database but it doesn't work.
It says the password is to long.

```
    public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Users;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        $password = $_POST['Users']['password'];
        $model->password = md5($password);
        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Increase size of the password field in the tabel and in rules in your user model increase that size as well for you model validation to result in true.

Comment: what the password length you are using in the model class rules?

Comment: your answer is correct milz thanks man :)

Comment: I downvoted for using md5 for password encryption, which is no longer considered safe, even by its creator (http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/md5-password-scrambler-no-longer-safe/12317). Look up Yii's password helper function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database and data type do you using for..?
if you use mysql , you can use char(32) or varchar(32) cause MD5 encrypted comes out to be 32 characters long.

and take care about your model rules

```
public function rules() {
   return array (
     array('password', 'length', 'max'=>20), 
     //length means your strings password that you entered can not more than 20 character
     //but its not effect with password encrypted result
   ); 
}
```

might be the message "the password is to long" appear because your rules() validator.

Comment: the probleme was the max size of the password